# MSVS 2015 phone emulator: how can I make sure that a file I have will be in the ApplicationData.LocalFolder directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm wanting to use CreateFile2 to read from a file on a phone app that I'm currently testing with one of the phone emulators.  However, from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx I know that I can only use CreateFile2 on files that are inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories.  The question is, how can I get my file of interest into one of those two directories beforehand?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding the file to the project, then selecting and right clicking on the file in solution explorer, going to properties, and setting the Content state to "YES" under Configuration Properties->General will land the file in the Package.InstalledLocation directory.